# Why does an initial BR break DOMDocument output?

Tags: domdocument

The following breaks DOMDocument, in that only the BR tag is output when trying to get the HTML back from it. What's the problem with having an initial BR tag?

```
  $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $dom->loadHTML("<br /><p>Here is some text!</p>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
  $value = $dom->saveHtml($dom->documentElement);
  print_r($value);
```

(Context: cleaning up text entered with a WYSIWYG.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://php.net/DOMDocument):

> Represents an entire HTML or XML document; serves as the root of the document tree.

You can't have multiple root elements in a document. You're just encountering error recovery.

Changing the HTML to this, for example:

```
<p>Here is some text!</p><p>Test</p>
```

Results in this:

> ```
> <p>Here is some text!<p>Test</p></p>
> ```

(with the second paragraph inserted into the first).

Wrapping the content in a single root element, such as a div, will resolve your specific issue:

```
<div><br><p>Here is some text!</p></div>
```

Gives:

> ```
> <div>
> <br><p>Here is some text!</p>
> </div>
> ```

That said, I suspect you would be better off with [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) for cleaning up user input HTML.